# How to access GitHub desktop web view on iOS

Tags: ios, github, mobile-safari

Like the title. I want to access GitHub desktop web version on Safari for iPhone. There used to be a button which you can switch to desktop or mobile view in the footer but now I can't see it anymore. When I turn on request desktop view on Safari, it still stay at mobile version. Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I'm afraid there is no way. Use your laptop or Android phones

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).